# Count whitespace in directory BASH

Tags: bash, shell

I just want to count whitespace char in directory but don't find how to do with AWK command.
Currently I have this code

```bsh
res=0
IFS="
"
cd DirPath
res2=0
res3=0
ws=0

for f in `find . ! -type d`; 
do
  let " res += `wc -l $f | awk '{print $1}'`  "
  let " res2 += `wc -c $f | awk '{print $1}'`  "
  let " res3 += `wc -w $f | awk '{print $1}'`  "
  let " ws += `wc -c $f | awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' 'END{print NR}'` "
done
```

but the result is very low (176) whereas I have 1300000 char in this directory

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand what it is you want to count. Can you provide an example in your question, please, showing what it is you're counting and how many of them are present in it

Comment: The output of `wc -c $f`  is a number, so what are you trying to do with `awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' 'END{print NR}'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of newline characters (`-l`), words (`-w`, which for `wc` are sequences of non-whitespace *characters*, so words are delimited by either whitespace or non-characters), characters (`-m`) and bytes (`-c`), you can do:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -lwmc
```

However note that because `cat` concatenates the files, it could give incorrect results for the word and character count if there are files that don't end in a whitespace *character* (text files should end in a newline character, which is a whitespace character) as that could end-up joining two bytes into one valid characters for instance, or joining two words together.

Example:

```
$ od -tx1 a
0000000 c3
0000001
$ od -tx1 b
0000000 a9
0000001
$ wc -m a b
0 a
0 b
0 total
$ cat a b | wc -m
1
```

```
$ printf foo > a
$ printf bar > b
$ wc -w a b
1 a
1 b
2 total
$ cat a b | wc -w
1
```

To count the whitespace characters, POSIXly, you could do:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | tr -cd '[:space:]' | wc -m
```

(with the same caveat about joining bytes into characters), but note that with GNU `tr`, that only works for single-byte characters (so not UTF-8 encoded non-ASCII characters for instance).

On GNU systems, you could resort to GNU `grep` and use:

```
grep -rzo '[[:space:]]' . | LC_ALL=C tr -cd '\0' | wc -c
```

Though note that because with `-z`, `grep` works on NUL-delimited records, that would end up slurping whole text files in memory (as text files typically don't contain NUL bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `GNU grep`:

```
grep -ro '[[:space:]]' | wc -l
```

Comment: After pipe char ?

Comment: no, just this...

Comment: That only counts SPC characters. Not the other types of whitespace. In particular, that approach can't be used for the NL character.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas isn't that what OP requested. Else I don't understand the question...

Comment: With GNU tools (`-o` is a GNU extension anyway), `grep -rzo '[[:space:]]' . | LC_ALL=C tr -cd '\0' | wc -c` could work.

Comment: Thank you I think the last GNU is right I found a well result

Answer (score 0):

```
cd DIRPATH
res2=0
res3=0
ws=0
let " ws += `grep -rzo '[[:space:]]' . | LC_ALL=C tr -cd '\0' | wc -c` "

for f in `find . ! -type d`; 
do
let " res += `wc -l $f | awk '{print $1}'`  "
let " res2 += `wc -c $f | awk '{print $1}'`  "
let " res3 += `wc -w $f | awk '{print $1}'`  "
done
```

The previous code give you number of whitespace char in directory on ws var

Comment: Are you answering your own question?